# PHP ISSET Function Not Excuted

Tags: php

In My Source When I press the Remove Button,inside isset code not excuted.can any one help me,

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<?php

$dbc=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","elvis_store") or die("Error Connecting to Mysql Database");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


echo "Hello";
foreach($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id){

$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE id=$delete_id";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("Error Querying Database");

}

echo "Customer(s) Removed";


}



$query="SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die("Query Syntaxt is Incorrect");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']." ".$row['email'];
echo "<br/>";




}



mysqli_close($dbc);

?>

<input type="submit" name"submit" value="Remove"/>
</form>




</body>
```

Comment: Please update your answer with full code and formated post.

Comment: Why are you sure `submit` variable is sent?

Comment: Maybe you haven't POSTed the 'submit'; variable in your form?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this

```
 name"submit"
```

is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))  {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the html is incorrect -> name"submit" have to be name="submit"

Second, I recomened you to first check if $_POST['submit'] is set and if it is do the php else show the form.